# How to change my Python version on CentOS for scripts executed via apache?

Tags: centos, python

I have a site say site.com/weather/a1.py

When I try to execute this file, this shows the version of Python as 2.6 whereas If I execute it by logging into terminal via Putty it shows me the Python version as 3.6

Can some one educate me on how to use Python3.6 for files executed via cgi-bin also?

Note : I recently changed my Python version using here

Comment: can you provide apache version and operating system you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have mod_wsgi apache module for 2.6 in apache that is why apache refer to older python version. You can install newer version of mod_wsgi using below commands.

**Redhat / Centos**

List available mod_wsgi versions

```
yum  list *mod_wsgi*
```

Select correct version and install with yum.

```
yum install python36u-mod_wsgi
```

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
```

Reatsrt apache after successful installation, then it will load python version 3.x in apache configuration.

Specifically for CentOS

After doing above you need to do these also

```
1.Remove mod_python.so from apache httpd.conf 
2.python.conf might be available either in /etc/httpd/conf or /etc/http/conf.d
3.Comment out all the lines in it
4.Add WSGI alias as mentioned over [here][1]
5.Then restart apache
```

Comment: After doing this, I need to disable mod_python.so which I did but now I am getting internal server error for python file

Comment: Can you provide apache error log entries for the same

Comment: I solved it actually..

Comment: Mentioned over where?

Answer (score 1):

First, find out where the 3.6 version of python comes from:

```
which python
```

also, check where your python3 is installed.

```
which python3
```

Check using `ls -l` to see if either path is a soft link.
Add/change the first line in a1.py to use the appropriate shabang line. E.g.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Remember, the apache server's PATH is most likely not the same as the one you use.

Comment: I am always getting this when I run which python3
/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

Comment: Your python3 may not be correctly installed as `python3` but you can still use the full path to the 3.6 version of python in your #! shabang line

Comment: I believe it's still not working..this is where my Python3.6 is installed #!/usr/local/bin/python3.6 and when I run which python3.6 from command line it shows the correct path but when I try to run it from the webserver it shows me a error..it might be a permission error?

Comment: post the error please

Comment: I dont have error to post it

When I execute it from server like site.com/weather/a1.py this is the message I am getting

Comment: 1 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] Instead of 3.6.3 the first line indicates it's still pointing to 2.6.6 ..This is Plesk with CentOS

Comment: All bets are off if you are using a control panel type system that's why questions about systems using them are not topical here.

Comment: mmm..Is there any way around?